# Telling horizontal from vertical planes

Tags: math

I have planes in 3D space defined by a normal vector and a center point.  I'd like to determine whether these planes are horizontal or perpendicular to the ground floor, or neither.  Usually, this can be found by is how it can be found:

```
a.b = |a||b|cos(t)
```

where `a` and `b` are two 3D vectors.

If `a.b` = 0, then they are perpendicular to each other; If `a.b` is equal to the product of lengths of `a` and `b`, the cosine of `t` is 1 and `t` is 0, so they are parallel

But I don't have a ground plane!!!!

Many thanks

Comment: How do you have a ground floor if you don't have a ground plane?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you can't introduce a ground floor into your calculations even if it is not present in the set of planes in your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to identify what you're calling a ground plane.  A couple ways of determining this plane are:

1. Pick a reference ground plane.  For instance if you're interested in
   using the X-Y plane as your ground plane, the normal you would use
   is just `<0, 0, 1>`.
2. If your situations doesn't permit easy use of an axially aligned reference
   plane, pick three non-colinear points on your reference ground plane, `T`,
   `U`, `V`.  Then the normal to the plane containing the three points
   is given by `N = +/-[ (U-T) x (V-T) ]` where `x` is the cross product
   operator.

Comment: bingo, the normal vector (0,0,1) indeed does the trick. The problem for me was that I have no reference ground plane, and a zero vector ir obviously wrong. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

If your ground plane is horizontal, then a horizontal plane will have a normal with x- and y-components of zero, and a vertical plane will have a normal with a z-component of zero.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to comparing planes, "horizontal" and "vertical" don't really have meaning unless you have at least 2 planes, a reference place and a plane to compare. Once you have a reference plane, you can then define "horizontal" as being "Prallel to the reference plane" and "vertical" as being "Perpendicular to the reference plane".

But, in all cases, you *need* a reference plane. (and, chances are, your coordinate system probably gives you an intrinsic one, often found at Zeros)

Comment: Thnx, looks like (0,0,1) is the gith answer